# Error during the compilation of DicomToMesh

Tags: c++, bash, cmake, vtk

I'm trying to compile DicomToMesh following this [tutorial](https://github.com/AOT-AG/DicomToMesh). At some point,it says to do :

```
`ccmake ..`  #opens ccmake window

Within the ccmake window, pass the path to your vtk installation or vtk build directory. In my case, it looks like that :

    CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE                 DEBUG                                        
    CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX             /usr/local                                   
    USE_VTK_DICOM                    OFF                                          
    VTK_DIR                          /home/eidelen/Development/libs/vtk/build

Press c and then g. Now you are back in terminal and ready to build.

    make
```

well,since after the compilation of the VTK package I got this message :

> Build files have been written to: /mnt/c/Users/"Mario
>   Zio"/Desktop/OrtogOn/Tools/VTK-Release-build"

on the VTK_DIR I tried to write :

> /mnt/c/Users/"Mario Zio"/Desktop/OrtogOn/Tools/VTK-Release-build

or

> /mnt/c/Users/"Mario Zio"/Desktop/OrtogOn/Tools/VTK-build

but they aren't accepted. The error message is :

> CMake Error at lib/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
>
> By not providing "FindVTK.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "VTK", but CMake did not find one. Could not find a package configuration file provided by "VTK" with any of the following names:
>
> VTKConfig.cmake
>
> vtk-config.cmake
>
> Add the installation prefix of "VTK" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "VTK_DIR"
>      to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "VTK" provides a
>      separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

Also,according with this [thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.vtk.user/79608),I have also used these paths as VTK_DIR inside the ccmake window :

```
/mnt/c/Users/"Mario Zio"/Desktop/OrtogOn/Tools//VTK-Release-build/bin

/mnt/c/Users/"Mario Zio"/Desktop/OrtogOn/Tools/VTK-build/bin
```

but the error I get is always the same. What should I do ?

NB 1 : Inside the bin folders of the VTK tool I see no files. Is this correct ?

NB 2 : I'm using the ubuntu bash that I have installed on windows 10.

Comment: VTK_DIR is the folder containing CMakeCache.txt and also VTKConfig.cmake

Comment: `Inside the bin folders of the VTK tool I see no files.` - You haven't **built** VTK, you have just *configure* it. Building is performed using `make`. As error message suggests, `VTK_DIR` variable should point to the directory with one of the files: `VTKConfig.cmake` or `vtk-config.cmake`. Check that.